# JQuery, how to apply the same mouseover effect to multiple divs with the same classes? help please?

Tags: jquery-selectors, mouseover, html, rollovers

i am new to jQuery and i am having some rollover issues, i am trying to apply the same "roll over" effect to multiple divs, and it seems to work, the only thing is when i roll over an element all of my divs get the same effect, when i would like them to apply the effect one at a time on mouse over,  here is my code

```
  $('div.pitem').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $('div.p-tab').toggleClass('pheader-bar-selected');
  });
  $('div.pitem').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $('div.p-fline').toggleClass('pfooter-bar-selected');
  });
```

I do realize that i have the same classes on all of my divs but i was hoping to find a way to do this with out giving every single div a unique class or id, any help would be amazing thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing currently is on every hover you toggle the CSS class on all elements selected by `div.p-tab`, which will be any DIV with the CSS class p-tab.

What you want to do is only toggle the CSS class on elements next to the hovered element in your HTML structure `div.pitem`.

To find the currently hovered item, in your event use `this` keyword, and turn it into a jQuery object by using `$(this)`.  To find elements next to (adjacent) you will use the `siblings` function.  You can also combine your two hover events.

```
$('div.pitem').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() { 
    $(this).siblings('div.p-tab').toggleClass('pheader-bar-selected');
    $(this).siblings('div.p-fline').toggleClass('pfooter-bar-selected');
}); 


<div class="grid_3 portfolio-item">
    <div class="p-tab pheader-bar">
        <span class="tfm-drpa">&raquo;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pitem">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <h2 class="pcontent">Consectetuer Adipiscing Elit<span class="ptitlelines">///</span></h2>
    <div class="p-fline pfooter-bar"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response! her eis my html code, i have 4 blocks of this

Comment: <div class="grid_3 portfolio-item">
<div class="p-tab pheader-bar"><span class="tfm-drpa">&raquo;</span></div>
<div class="pitem"><a href="#"></a></div>
<h2 class="pcontent">Consectetuer Adipiscing Elit<span class="ptitlelines">///</span></h2>
<div class="p-fline pfooter-bar"></div>
</div>

Comment: you can view what im developing here - http://blog.thefragilemachine.com/  thanks again! btw its the 4 big imge type elements right below the logo

Comment: No problem, looks like you got it working.  If my answer solves your problem, please select it as the accepted answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at $(this).

Explained at: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Here is how I use it to give you an example

```
// megalink hover
$("div.megalink").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background','#e1eefd');
    $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid #0470B8');
 }, function(){
    $(this).css('background','#ffffff');
    $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid #EBE7DE');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the fast replies! , although still not quite working, its kinda weird im trying to have it so when the user rolls over one element/div it activates 2 different divs,if that makes sense?